# mongodb regex with a range of unicode characters

Tags: regex, mongodb, unicode, pcre, cjk

I try to use the mongodb (version 3.4) $regex operator with a range of unicode characters. But I don't manage to make it work (I'm using robomongo to test it).

I tried the following:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find(
{ 
    "field": { 
            $regex: /[\x{20000}-\x{2A6D6}]/
      } 
})
```

It output the following error:

> Error: Line 4: Invalid regular expression

The regex I set up must match all characters of the CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B.
It seems not related to the use of CJK unicode hex values, because I have the same error with a more simpler regex like 
`$regex: /[\x{0}-\x{1}]/`

Can you help me understand why my regex does not work ?

Comment: Isn't that pattern supposed to be parsed with JS regex? Try the `/(?:[\uD840-\uD868][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6])/` equivalent. Or, check if it is ES6 aware: `/[\u{20000}-\u{2A6D6}]/u`

Comment: `/[\u{20000}-\u{2A6D6}]/u` produces an error (u is not a valid regex flag), and without the `u`, the error is that the regex is invalid

Comment: What if you use a string literal? `$regex: '[\x{0}-\x{1}]'`

Comment: `/(?:[\uD840-\uD868][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6])/` is accepted by mongo but produces no result (it should be, considered the data set I have), I m still wondering why

Comment: @revo `$regex: '[\x{0}-\x{1}]'` produces the same error "Invalid regular expression"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the simple quotes to support PCRE expressions (cf https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/ ) and you have to escape the backslash. So the following should work:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find(
   { "field": { 
      $regex: '[\\x{20000}-\\x{2A6D6}]' 
      }
   })
```